# Can i make the custom source&sink from local server(file or dbs..) to dataflow directly?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to make the custom source&sink from local server (files or dbs) to dataflow directly. so i wonder whether it is possible.

If it's possible, What should I be carefully to make it?
FYI, I have never made the custom source&sink.
But I used once GCS, dataflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataflow's [custom IO framework](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) can read from arbitrary sources and write to arbitrary sinks. You can certainly write connectors to various types of files and databases.

However, when executing pipelines on a remote service, like Google Cloud Dataflow in the cloud, depending on several factors, it may not be able to access services running on your local machine. Moreover, such local services may not scale well-enough to get a performant data-processing pipeline.

Thus, it might be better to move data to a cloud-based service, like Google Cloud Storage or Google BigQuery.